# How to mount an attached EC2 volume in CLI?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mount

I just recovered data from an ec2 snapshot and created a volume with the data, i also attached the volume to my working instance, but I have problems mounting the new volume. On ec2-describe-volumes, I do get the find new volume created.
i-14305121  /dev/sdi

---

How do I mount this /dev/sdi on to a directory so that I can access the files on it? I tried mount /dev/sdi, but I got an error: mount: special device /dev/sdi does not exist.

---

On running lsblk from terminal, i get this

```
dev1@ip-10-244-164-7:/$ lsblk /dev/sdi
lsblk: /dev/sdi: not a block device
dev1@ip-10-244-164-7:/$ lsblk /dev/xvdi
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvdi 202:128  0   8G  0 disk
```

---

On running mount /dev/xvdi, I also get this error. Other details of fdisk, mtab are also given here:

```
dev1@ip-10-244-164-7:/$ sudo mount /dev/xvdi /backup
mount: can't find /backup in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
dev1@ip-10-244-164-7:/$ cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults    0 0
dev1@ip-10-244-164-7:/$ cat etc/mtab 
/dev/xvda1 / ext4 rw 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,mode=0755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
none /run/user tmpfs rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755 0 0
dev1@ip-10-244-164-7:/$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/xvda1: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders, total 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/xvda1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/xvdi: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders, total 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/xvdi doesn't contain a valid partition table
dev1@ip-10-244-164-7:/$
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is a good answer, try running:

```
lsblk /dev/sdi
```

And it may list partitions that exists on that drive like this:

```
sdi
|--sdi1
|--sdi2
|--sdi3
```

If you have something like sdi1 you can try to mount it:

```
mount /dev/sdi1 /your/folder/here
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try

```
mount /dev/xvdi /your/folder
```

In EC2 devices are named differently from what they promise in AWS console. See [EC2: EBS device id confusion (/dev/sdf vs. /dev/xvdf)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102551/ec2-ebs-device-id-confusion-dev-sdf-vs-dev-xvdf)

Comment: just tried that, got an output as:
`mount: can't find /backup in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab`

Comment: this error message is unrelated to the original problem you described. I'd suggest to post another question to serverfault.com