# How to detect new disk plugin?

Tags: linux

Is there a linux command that shows the disk plugin? What I want to do is looping and find new disk plugin, mount the new disk to some specified path and read the data in it, but it seems like a BIOS feature, how to list the plugin disk?

Comment: here, I got the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200960/find-all-storage-devices-attached-to-a-linux-machine

Answer (score 1):

Use `udev` to detect plugged/unplugged devices.

You can write a `udev rule` in order to detect a specific device you are interested.

[Here](http://hackaday.com/2009/09/18/how-to-write-udev-rules/) is a tutorial on it.