# Detecting a new disk (in Bash) or trigger on new disk

Tags: linux, bash, udev

I'd like to use a Raspberry Pi to quickly backup camera memory cards (and similar) to a defined storage location, and ideally for it to do that with any new disk I plug into it.

The easiest way for me to do the backup is with a bash script, so I'm wondering if I should launch on boot and loop until disks are added or if there's a system trigger that I could use?

There's a couple of suggestions at these two questions:

- [How to detect new disk plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172829/how-to-detect-new-disk-plugin)
- [Find all storage devices attached to a Linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200960/find-all-storage-devices-attached-to-a-linux-machine)

Which is the more appropriate method?

Comment: Only one of them deals with "new" devices...

Comment: Explicitly, yes. But if you find all devices on boot, and then check again a minute later, you have a list of new devices!