# Linux command to display name of file system used for boot/root partitions

Tags: linux, command, filesystems

I have been looking for the right command to display the name of the file system used for boot on Linux but have not been able to find anything. I have tried stat/boot but I am not sure that it is the answer that I am looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all storage devices attached to a Linux machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200960/find-all-storage-devices-attached-to-a-linux-machine)

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do it, but

```
stat -f -c %T /boot
```

is one. Note that the `-f` parameter which is used to request filesystem information as opposed to file information.

Comment: Thanks I'm pretty sure that is what I was looking for.